# Can't make non-smooth movement script in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Since yesterday I started working on a 2D game, and I found a problem when I was making the character movement. I wanted to make the character move left, right, up and down and since I was having a hardtime using the new Unity's Input System, I used the old Input.GetAxis(). My character was moving but I didn't like the smooth movement, I wanted the player to always move at the same speed and to stop in the moment that I released the movement keys. But know I can only make him move a bit everytime I press the keys.

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AlternativeController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    bool canMove = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        if (canMove)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
        {
            transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("left"))
        {
            transform.Translate(-speed, 0, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("up"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, speed, 0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("down"))
        {
            transform.Translate(0, -speed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Input.GetKeyDown` is only called once. You need to release the key to call the method again. You want the character to move as long as you press the key, so change `Input.GetKeyDown` with `Input.GetKey`. Will be called as long as you hold the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

> ```
> Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
> Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
> ```

This will use the more portable `GetAxis` of the old input system, without the smoothing of `GetAxis()`.

Alternatively, as said in the comments, you can replace `Input.GetKeyDown()` with `Input.GetKey()` to check if a key is being held.